# How do I append elements with duplicate names using MSXML & C++?

Tags: c++, msxml, msxml4

I am write some code to update a XML DOM using MSXML4 & C++.  I need a method that appends a child element to a parent element.  The code I have written below works until the title of the child matches the title of another child under the parent.  I cannot change the title of the children so I need to find a way to append them to the parent.

Can anyone provide some guidance?

```
// this call creates '<parent><child/></parent>'
AppendChild("/root/parent", "child");

// this call attempts to create '<parent><child/><child/></parent>' but the DOM remains     unchanged ('<parent><child/></parent>')
AppendChild("/root/parent", "child");


void AppendChild(const std::string kPathOfParent, const std::string kNameOfChild)
{
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pElement = m_pXmlDoc->createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, kNameOfChild.c_str(), m_xmlns.c_str());

    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pParent = m_pXmlDoc->selectSingleNode(kPathOfParent.c_str());
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pNewChild = pParent->appendChild(pElement);
}
```

Comment: Hey, you're passing C-strings where you should be passing BSTRs.  All of these COM methods take BSTRs.  Please go read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx

Comment: Is appendChild() returning a non-NULL pointer?

Comment: Thanx Jeff about reminding me to switch to BSTR's.  I had forgotten to do so.

Remy, the pNewChild is not NULL for either of the child elements added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly what the problem was, but somewhere my binaries were out of step.  I rebuilt the entire project via 'Clean Solution' instead of just the 'Build Solution' option.  Now both children are created using the code above.  It is not clear to me why I was able to step in to the code via the debugger, but the second child was never created until I cleaned the solution.

Jeff & Remy, thank-you for your comments.